# Continuity of power series proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I dont understand this proof of continuity, the part under the red line.
1. Why is |y-x| < T-|x| .. where did they get the y from? Also how does this imply |y|

Comment: **I dont understand this proof of continuity, the part under the red line.
1. Why is |y-x| < T-|x| .. where did they get the y from? Also how does this imply |y|<T and |x|<T 
Then I dont understand where it says if we choose delta  to be smaller of delta_0 and T-|x| and from then on. I dont understand the reasoning behind it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention is to prove continuity at $x$, that is
$$ \forall\epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,\forall y\colon |y-x|<\delta\to |f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon.$$
So you might expect a proof to run as follows:

> Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then let $\delta = (\ldots)$.
>   We want to show that with this choice $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $y$ with $|y-x|<\delta$.
>   So let $y$ be an real number with $|y-x|<\delta$. Then ...

That's where the $y$ comes from. And as we can demand that $\delta\le T-|x|$ (and whatever additional conditions come to our mind upon further investigation), we can safely assume that $|y-x|<T-|x|$.
And so on. This is just the way that more or less *every* epsilon-delta proof runs.